# How to search for all occurrences in a string that are not preceded by a certain character?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have the following string **`dataOne[1][2][3]./../dataTwo[4][5][6].dataThree/./dataFour`** and I want to find all occurrences of the sub string `./` that are not preceded by a `.` or `/`.

I wrote the following reg. ex. **`(?!(\/|\.))\.\/`** and I expected to match only the first occurrences of the `./` sub string that is located after the `dataOne[1][2][3]` sub string, but it doesn't work: does anyone know where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative lookbehinds are specified using `(?<!)`, not `(?!)`, the latter which is for negative lookaheads.  Also, you can use a character class to express the characters which you want to blacklist.  Putting this all together, you may use the following regex pattern:

```
(?<![./])\./
```

### Demo

Comment: I copied it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6CLoNj/1), but it doesn't work

Comment: It works...check the demo link.

Comment: ... Ok, now it works thanks (I will accpet the response)

Comment: That was what I was trying to tell you in the previous comment: Stackoverflow does not allow to accept answers in the first 15 minutes of their posting